# Why does UIButton render the titleLabel so terribly on iOS 7?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uibutton, uikit, rendering

I'm using IcoMoon to create a custom font that I use to generate Icons.  This however plays no role as the same phenomenon occurs using Helvetica.

Why do 2 things occur on titleLabel of a UIButton on iOS 7?

- The right edge of the label is cut off (the button frame is much wider, but the label frame is getting cut off
- there is a dark ring around the light gray image.

[image: Dark Ring on Light Image]

This looks absolutely horrible and it's basically unacceptable.  We'll have to render graphics ourselves and localize images where appropriate.

I would be grateful for any info.  The only thing that distinguishes these two checkmarks is that they have different colors set for titleColor

Comment: Did you changed the button type to custom?

Comment: yes.  now I'm just writing because StackOverflow needs at least 15 characters.  :-)

Answer (score -1):

Try setBackgroundImage: instead of setImage:

Comment: The question states I'm talking about titleLabel.